# DataTables Input Range and PDF export

Tags: datatables

I have a table generated with some data which has already an export to PDF button. What I want to accomplish is to have an input range criteria where data will be filtered and then export to PDF. The problem is that even if the table is re-drawed, when I click Export to PDF the new filtered data is not generated. 
I cannot find a way to combine the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
} );
```

and this one below, since I correctly get an error that Datatable cannot be 
re-initialized. Any suggestions on that?

```
$('#mexample').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: 'Save current page',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    page: 'current'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: Are you using server processing or client side? and normally if you filter by search automatically the print or pdf export take the only rows shown after filtering, why you need to redraw the table?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579477/data-table-with-export-option-should-export-only-selected-data I believe this is what you are heading for

Comment: I have first used AJAX in order to send 2 Search Input field values I have created to a php file which peforms the query and then builds the Table but this solution is ok to re-draw the table. Actually it re-draws in some way the table by displaying the filtered results, but the export pdf is not displayed. So I then tried the 2nd solution from the datatables input range which works but I could not combine it with the pdf. I will use the export rows : {search:'applied'} as it is in the answer. Thank you